# What is formula /algorithm Developer contribution graph on github

Tags: github

Which algorithm / formula github.com is using to calculate the following developer contribution graph? any help will be highly appreciated. 
[image]

Comment: this question is offtopic, and will be probably closed, but to give you a quick answer - `The Contributors graph shows commits made by the top 100 contributors over the lifetime of your project. This graph doesn't include merge commits or commits with zero changes.`

Comment: This question is quite different as you mentioned in your comment. Contribution graph curve must have some values which they show on graph.  I want to know about the algorithm which github using to calculate graph.

Comment: The values are number of commits on the specific day. I quoted help article from github explaining where the values come from. But, still asking for algorithms is off-topic on StackOverflow